# How to synchronize ObservableCollection between applications

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, client-server

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to find a way to synchronize an ObservableCollection between applications. Basically, one would be the server that has a collection of strings, and the other would be the client which would have that same list and display it in a GUI. When a string is modified on the server, I want the modification to be reflected on the client.

I'm not very familiar with server-client architectures or frameworks and would like to know where to start. So far I have looked at the WCF architecture and it looks like it might be a bit overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish, but I could be wrong.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is the standard way of performing inter-process and inter-machine communications for .NET applications and it works very well. You need your client application to connect to the server and get the current state of the collection. Then each time the collection changes the client needs to be notified so it can apply the same change locally. There are many resource on the Web and at MSDN describing how to create a WCF connection.